# Bash: scp fails due to "(" character in variable name

Tags: bash, shell

I have below script with name `tmp__(.sh`

```
FILE_NAME=`basename $0`
THIS=$(readlink -f "$0")
ip="10.10.10.121"
tmp="./tmp"
scp -q "$THIS" "$ip:$tmp/$FILE_NAME"
```

Running above scripts gives

```
>>sh tmp__\(.sh
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `scp -t ./tmp/tmp__(.sh'
lost connection
```

I understand we can escape characters from a string but how to escape `(` from a variable name?

Comment: The error message says `scp -t` but the script has `scp -q`. Why the discrepancy?

Comment: Plus where are you running `bash -c`? That error message does not appear to be generated by your provided code.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I have posted as is . This is what I get when I run "sh tmp__\\(.sh"

Comment: Add to your question (no comment) how  you run your script.

Comment: Run it with `sh 'tmp__\(.sh'`.

Comment: @Wiimm It doesn't work nor it is an option even if it worked. Need to somehow fix in script itself.

Comment: Hmm. Try changing the line that sets `FILE_NAME` to `FILE_NAME=$(basename "$0")`?

Comment: @Shawn have already tried that. No luck!

Comment: Don't mix `\`...\`` and `$(...)` in the same script.

Comment: @Kaz Any reason for it?

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
scp "$THIS" $ip:/tmp/'$FILE_NAME'
```

It seems to work :

```
cat tmp__\(.sh
FILE_NAME=`basename $0`
echo $FILE_NAME
THIS=$(readlink -f "$0")
echo $THIS
ip="x.x.x.x"
scp "$THIS" $ip:/tmp/'$FILE_NAME'
```

```
./tmp__\(.sh
tmp__(.sh
/root/stackoverflow/tmp__(.sh
tmp__(.sh
```

Comment: Won't this create a remote file that is named `/tmp/$FILE_NAME` rather than `./tmp/tmp__(.sh`?

Comment: No it did create a file named tmp__(.sh . ```  ls -l /tmp/ | grep tmp.*sh
-rwxr--r--. 1 root root 129 Sep 23 03:58 tmp__(.sh
```

Comment: It seems to work but can you please explain why?